# Helm Install of Rancher Failing with Image Pull Failures

Tags: rancher, k3s

I am following this guide [here](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/install-rancher-on-k8s/) to install Rancher on a K3S installation. When I run this following command

```
helm install rancher rancher-stable/rancher --namespace cattle-system --set hostname=rancher.mydomainhere.com
```

I can see this this deploys 2 rancher pods and a rancher-webhook pod but a 3rd rancher pod fails to install with different errors:

```
Failed to pull image "rancher/rancher:v2.5.5": rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition 
desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/rancher/rancher:v2.5.5": 
failed commit on ref "layer-sha256:d8a8a5ffce76595d596b6177d992a1c602ef017c51716aac41a132eacd31c725": 
unexpected commit digest sha256:179766804121211915209ddc992a80eba373be27858c1d67c1de65a7db05845d, 
expected sha256:d8a8a5ffce76595d596b6177d992a1c602ef017c51716aac41a132eacd31c725: failed precondition
                 
Failed to pull image "rancher/rancher:v2.5.5" unexpected commit digest sha256
```

Or

```
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/rancher/rancher:v2.5.5": 
failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: 
Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e0/e02481bb39c88f0352ed7ae1998f2860a4816a8d5c3ba3b397b972849f657e2e/data?verify=1613998137-u6Ymb9X6kgFrZFmuDAS2bRlVKjc%3D": 
dial tcp: lookup production.cloudflare.docker.com: no such host
```

Monitoring the deployment shows it has timed out.

```
Waiting for deployment "rancher" rollout to finish: 0 of 3 updated replicas are available...
Waiting for deployment "rancher" rollout to finish: 1 of 3 updated replicas are available...
Waiting for deployment "rancher" rollout to finish: 2 of 3 updated replicas are available...
Waiting for deployment spec update to be observed...
Waiting for deployment "rancher" rollout to finish: 2 of 3 updated replicas are available...
error: deployment "rancher" exceeded its progress deadline
```

What is going wrong & how do I fix this?

Edited as I found a way to get this to "work" although I'm not sure what the issue is. I got this to work by running the same command line on Linux (one of the VM hosts for the kubernetes servers) rather than on Windows (my dev machine). This is using the same versions of kubectl and helm with the same kube.config. The command works when run on Linux and fails when run on Windows.

Comment: Welcome, since this question doesn't have any code, it is off-topic here. It probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)